# How do I hyperlink to a certain section of my page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am making a one page website, I know that when you make a hyperlink you can sent it to a different file in your folder example: about From index.html. What I’m trying to do is make the page go to the about section that’s on the same index file.

Comment: first you should have researched for it and than you should ask here. If you have tried something you should show your efforts what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a **named anchor**. You use them in pairs:

```
<a href="#a">go to A</a> <-- the link
```

.... some content ...

```
<a name="a">Some Section Title</a> <-- the target
```

Comment: Well, we pretty much answered that at the same time :O

Comment: Thank you guys I didn’t know I needed the name attribute to make it work.

Comment: Thank you Diodeus!